# Косяк в 2 строках кода

Tags: php

Почему то не ъочет отрабатывать

```
<?php
    $friend_id = array_rand("120084909", "14019830", "94059601",  "68920114", "43350741", "51750847", "13163643", "118676151", "97938824" );
    echo $friend_id;
?>
```

Шлёт эрроры, при том на локалке обрабатывает О_О

Comment: У `array_rand()` параметром должно быть что?

> Шлёт эрроры, при том на локалке обрабатывает О_О

Очевидно, на локалке тупо отключены ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ids = array("120084909", "14019830", "94059601",  "68920114", "43350741", "51750847", "13163643", "118676151", "97938824");
    $friend_id = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
    echo $friend_id;
?>
```

**Документация: [array_rand](http://php.net//manual/ru/function.array-rand.php)**